# Q: git merge: old version of file remains

Tags: git

common branch M, my personal branch My. I want my branch to be in line with M, but it didn't happen (and no Conflicts):

```
git checkout M
git pull origin M
git checkout My
git merge M -m "local merge"
```

But when I look at say build_version.txt it's still my branch's file and not the variant of file from M as I expected.

Please advise

Comment: Merge takes contributions from both branches, by default.

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation is wrong.  You will need to adjust your expectation of what Git will do.

Merge is, fundamentally, about *combining changes*.

Meanwhile, commits store *snapshots*, not changes.  That is, each commit has a complete snapshot of *every file* (that Git knew about, at the time you, or whoever, made that snapshot).

This leaves us with a dilemma: how can we combine changes, when we don't even have any changes?

You might object, because whenever you look at a commit—with, e.g., `git log -p`, or `git show raw-commit-hash-ID`—you *see* changes.  To understand how this works, let's take a closer look at a commit.  (Don't worry that this is long!  We will eventually get to `git merge`.)

#### What is a commit?

Above, I said that a commit stores a snapshot.  This is true, but it's not complete.  It's like saying that a human has a head.  Sure, all humans—well, all *live* ones—have heads.  But a head alone does not make a human, even if that might be the most important part for some particular purpose, such as reading a StackOverflow Q&A.

The first thing to know about a commit is that it's *numbered*.  These commit numbers are not simple counting numbers—we don't have commit #1, followed by #2, then #3, and so on.  Instead, each commit has a random-looking, and very large, number, that gets represented as a big hexadecimal value such as `a123456`, which might be followed by `7f31242` or something.  (Compare this to, e.g., SVN, which *does* have simple sequential numbers: rev 12346 comes right after rev 12345.)

The commit number of any commit is unique across *every* Git repository everywhere.  That's why these numbers have to be so big and ugly.  The number is actually a cryptographic checksum of the commit's content, which means that neither the number nor the content can ever change, and all Gits everywhere will compute the *same* number for that particular content.  This is how two Gits can know whether they share some commit (or in fact any internal Git object, not just a commit).  One Git hands the other Git a number, for a commit the one Git has.  The other Git looks in its database: does it have that number in it?  If so, it has that commit.  If not, it gets that commit—all of its content, that is—from the other Git, and now they both have that commit.

So that's how Git *finds* a commit: by its number.  But that's still not what it *is*, so let's look a bit closer.  Each commit consists of two parts:

- There's that snapshot we've mentioned several times.  (This is actually implemented indirectly, as a *tree object*, though you don't normally need to care about this.)  Here Git has, saved forever, a *full copy* of every file that Git knew about at the time the commit got made.  The files inside the commit are not ordinary files, though: they're in a special, Git-only format, compressed and de-duplicated.  (This is implemented through yet more of these internal objects, specifically *blob objects*, but again you don't need to know this.)
- Besides the required snapshot, each commit has some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself: who made it, when, and why (their log message), for instance.  (Technically, one metadata line gives the hash ID of the snapshot, but yet again, you don't need to know this.)

So a commit consists of this metadata-plus-snapshot.  That's what a commit is: a numbered entity, holding some metadata and a snapshot.  The metadata includes your name, if you made the commit.  But it also includes something purely for Git itself.  Each commit holds, in its metadata, the commit numbers—the hash IDs—of some set of *previous* commits.

Most commits are "ordinary commits".  What makes a commit ordinary is that it has, as its previous-commit hash ID, just *one* hash ID.  This hash ID is that of the immediately previous commit.  We call this one immediately-previous commit the *parent* of the commit.  These hash IDs allow Git to access a whole chain of commits just by knowing the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.

We can draw this situation like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, the letters stand in for real commit hash IDs, which are too big and ugly to bother with.  Of course we'll run out of letters quickly (which is one reason Git uses those big ugly hash IDs), but as long as we only draw a few at a time, they'll do.  Older commits are on the left and newer ones are on the right, here.

Somehow, we tell Git the hash ID of the *last* commit, `H`, in this chain.  Git can use this to read out the data-and-metadata, including the full snapshot of every file.  So that allows Git to *check out* the commit, extracting all the files to our work area.  But that also gives Git the raw hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

This means that instead of just extracting the snapshot for `H`, Git can now use the hash ID of `G` to extract the snapshot of `G`.  Then Git can *compare* the snapshots.  The special format of a snapshot makes this a bit easier, with the de-duplication: Git can skip right over (de)duplicated files and only bother comparing files that are actually *different* in the two commits.

By comparing two different files stored under the same name, Git can then figure out which *lines* changed in those two versions of that file.  That's what `git log -p` or `git show` shows us.  Git didn't *store* the changes—it stored two snapshots—but comparing the first snapshot to the second tells Git what changed.

Of course, now that Git has the hash ID of commit `G`, it can extract `G`'s metadata, which gives Git the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`.  Git can go through the exact same process as last time, and show us what changed.  From `F`, Git can move back one more step, to whatever commit comes before `F`, and so on.  This process can go on forever, or rather, until Git comes across the very first commit.  That first commit doesn't *have* a previous (parent) commit.  That lets `git log` stop going backwards.

There's one big hitch here.  We said *somehow, we tell Git the hash ID of the last commit*.  But how?  Did we write down that hash ID on paper, or a whiteboard, or what?  Maybe we saved it in a file, and listed out the contents of the file and used cut-and-paste with the mouse.  (This method *does* work, by the way, at least for a while.)  But these are all silly methods.  We have a *computer*.  Why not have *it* save the hash ID somewhere?

#### Branch names

This is where branch names come in.  A branch name like `main` or `develop` or `my` or whatever you like simply stores the hash ID of *one* commit, which we—or Git—will then believe is the *last* commit in that chain of commits.  We can draw our current situation like this, then:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

if it's the branch name `main` that lets Git find commit `H`.

Once we have one branch name, though, we're tempted to add more.  Let's make a second branch name that *also* points to commit `H`, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch1, main
```

These two branch names allow us to pick out one commit.  Both names pick out commit `H` right now, so in a sense, it doesn't matter which name we use; but if all branch names always had to pick out the *same* commit, that would be a problem.  So that's not the case, and when the branch names start to move around, we'll need a way to remember which *name* we are using.

To handle this, let's attach a special name, `HEAD`, written in all uppercase exactly like this, to exactly *one* branch name at a time.  Whatever *name* `HEAD` is attached to, we'll say that this is our *current branch*.  Whatever *commit* that name points to, we'll say that this is our *current commit*.

We do this attaching with `git checkout` or, in Git 2.23 or later, `git switch`.  For instance, after `git switch main` we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch1, main (HEAD)
```

but after `git switch branch1` we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- branch1 (HEAD), main
```

Either way, we'll be on commit `H`, but after the second switch, we're using the name `branch1` to get there.  (Note: The `switch` command subsumes the "safe" part of `git checkout`; the "unsafe" part of `git checkout` is now in `git restore`.  The old `git checkout` command, which has both the "safe" and "unsafe" operating modes, still exists.  If your Git predates Git 2.23, you must use `git checkout` here, and hope it doesn't accidentally use the unsafe subset.)

Now that we're on `branch1`, let's make a *new commit*.  (We won't worry about the *exact* mechanism; let's just assume that you know what `git commit` does.  It's complicated if we get into every detail, but you've been doing it OK so far, no doubt, so you know enough here.)  We'll fuss with files and `git add` and `git commit`, which will build a new snapshot `I` with appropriate metadata.  New commit `I` will point back to existing commit `H`.  As the *last* step of `git commit`, Git will write `I`'s hash ID into the *current branch name*, so that we have this now:

```
          I   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

If we make another new commit, which we will call commit `J`, we will have:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
```

Now let's make a new branch name, using commit `H`—not `J`—as its initial stored hash ID.  We'll also get "on" this branch using `git checkout` or `git switch`.  Perhaps we run `git switch -c branch2 main`, for instance.  This gives us:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- branch2 (HEAD), main
```

Note how commit `H` is now the *current commit*, with `branch2` the *current branch*.  We now have, in our work area, the files from commit `H`, not the files from commit `J`.

Let's make two new commits now on `branch2`:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2 (HEAD)
```

Note that commits up through and including `H` are on *all three* branches, while commits `I-J` are only on `branch1`, and `K-L` are only on `branch2`.  Commit `H` is the last commit on `main`; commit `J` is the last commit on `branch1`; and commit `L` is the last commit on `branch2`.

The purpose of the *names* is to locate these commits, and allow us to `git checkout` or `git switch` *to* those names so that as we make new commits, those names get updated.  What Git mainly stores—and exchanges with other Git repositories—is the *commits themselves*, though.  Any other Git repository has *its own* branch names.  They might use the same names we use, or not; if they do use the same names, they might pick out the same commits, or not.

#### A high-speed look at `git pull`

Before you merged, you ran:

> ```
> git checkout M
> git pull origin M
> ```

The `checkout` picked out your branch name `M`, attached your Git's `HEAD` there, and got you the last commit on that branch, via the hash ID recorded under that name.  The `git pull` then does something a bit complicated: it runs *two* commands.  The first one is `git fetch`—in this case, `git fetch origin M`—and the second one is configurable, but defaults to `git merge`.

The `git fetch` operation calls up some other Git, connecting that other Git to some other Git repository, based on the URL stored under the name `origin`.  They check *their* branch `M`, in this case, to see what *their* last commit is.  They hand your Git that commit's hash ID.  If your Git doesn't have this commit yet, your Git *gets* this commit, and any earlier commits as well that they have that you don't.  So now you have all the commits you both had earlier, plus any commits they had that you didn't.

This `git fetch` operation updates a **non-branch** name that your Git uses to remember the commit hash ID stored in *their* **branch** name `M`.  The non-branch name that your Git uses is `origin/M`.  (If your Git is truly ancient—older than 1.8.4—this kind of `git fetch` fails to update your `origin/M`; the rest still works, though, through a mechanism I won't describe.  If your Git is newer, technically your Git still uses the old mechanism.  It *also* updates `origin/M`, though, which makes the whole thing easier to think about.)

The *second* command now uses the updated hash ID—in `origin/M` in this case—to *incorporate* the new commits into your current branch, which is of course `M` due to the earlier `git checkout`.  As long as you didn't make your own commits here, this winds up doing what Git calls a *fast-forward merge*.  This thing is kind of misnamed: a fast-forward is not a merge at all.  It just marches your own branch name forward, so that your `M` and their `M` (now in your `origin/M`) will end up naming the *same commit*.

I'm going to stop using the name `M` as a *branch name* here, since I use these single uppercase letter things for *commit* names.  Let's call this branch `develop` instead.  We'll split up the `git pull` into its two separate components, so that we know exactly which commands really got used (with `git pull` we don't necessarily know which command ran after `git fetch`):

```
git checkout develop
git fetch
git merge origin/develop
```

We'll say that we also made our own branch, *not* named `develop` but rather `branch1`, as before.  When we started, we had:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

and we added our branch name and then our `I-J` commits:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop
```

Now we've run `git checkout develop` and then `git fetch`, which got us:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/develop
```

because *they* made two commits, `K-L`, on *their* `develop`, and we picked them up.

We now run (via `git pull`) `git merge origin/develop`.  **This does a fast-forward instead of a merge**, which gives us this as the result:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

Note how *no commits have changed*—they can't; it's literally impossible—but *our branch name `develop` now selects commit `L`*.  That's what the fast-forward did: it moved our branch name.

We're now ready to look at a true merge.

#### Merge (true merges, not fast-forwards)

We now switch back to our branch, `branch1` (the one you were calling `My`):

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

and now we run `git merge develop`.  The *name* develop here just serves to locate commit `L`.

(This means that instead of `git checkout develop; git pull origin develop; git checkout branch1` we could just run `git fetch` and then `git merge origin/develop`.  The name `origin/develop` will locate commit `L`.  We don't need to update our own name `develop` here.  In fact, we could probably just *delete* our name `develop` entirely!  We don't seem to need it any more.)

Git already knows what our current commit hash ID is.  Git can find this easily by reading `HEAD` to get the branch name, and then the branch name to get the hash ID, `J`.  We've now given Git another hash ID, that of commit `L`.  The merge command now needs to be able to turn these various snapshots into changes.  How will it do that?

We could try comparing the snapshots in `J` and `L`.  But that doesn't seem to work.  We want to *combine* changes; that just finds one set of changes: whatever's needed to turn `J` into `L`.  That's no good; we'd lose *our* work, if we just took the files from `L`.

No, the whole notion of *combining changes* calls for something else.  We need to find some sort of *common starting point*.  We need a commit where we, on our way to our commit `J`, and they, on the way to their commit `L`, were both in agreement.

So, look back at our drawing.  At commit `G`, we were both in agreement: we were both using commit `G`, with its snapshot.  At commit `H` we were still in agreement, both using `H` and its snapshot.  But then we went to `I`, which they don't have—we haven't given it to them yet, so they *still* don't have it—and they went to `K`, which *we* didn't have (but do now).  We went on to `J` and they went on to `L`.  So `H` is the *last shared commit*.  Git finds this by starting from the two ends, `J` and `L`, and working backwards.

Technically, Git is using the [Lowest Common Ancestor of a Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs) here.  Not all DAGs have just one LCA, and if there are two or more LCAs, Git has some answers to that, but we'll ignore those cases here.  You don't normally need to know all of this, but it's good to remember that the two-or-more-LCAs cases exist, as they can produce surprises.  It's also good to be able to eyeball simple graph drawings and identify the obvious LCAs, but when you need to find them in a tangled, realistic graph, just run `git merge-base --all` to have Git compute them for you.

Anyway, in this case, commit `H` is the LCA—or in Git's terms, the *merge base*.  It's the best common / shared ancestor commit of your latest commit and theirs.  Git now needs to find out what *changed*, between the common starting point—commit `H`—and your latest commit.  Git could do this one commit at a time: `H`-vs-`I`, then `I`-vs-`J`, and that would sometimes have some advantages, but Git just does it all at once by comparing the snapshot in `H` to the one in `J`, as if you had run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>
```

Whatever this diff finds, that's what *you* changed.  Then, Git runs a second diff:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>
```

Whatever this diff finds, that's what *they* changed.

Merge now simply (hah) combines these two sets of changes.  If all goes well, Git can combine these on its own.  Git will apply the combined changes to the snapshot from the merge base, in this case `H`.  That way you get *your* changes kept, and *their* changes *added*.

Last—and again this is only automatic if all goes well in the combining stage—Git will now make a new *merge commit*.  This is a slightly special kind of commit.  It's just like an ordinary commit in all ways but one: it has, as a parent, your *current commit* `J`.  It has a snapshot, as all commits do.  What makes it special, though, is that it has a *second* parent: commit `L`, the one Git found by the argument you gave to `git merge`.

We can draw the result like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- develop, origin/develop
```

Git writes the new merge commit's hash ID into the current branch name as usual, so now the *name* `branch1` points to new merge commit `M`.  The *snapshot* in `M` contains the result of Git's combining work, as applied to the snapshot from `H`, the merge base.  While there's no easy way to see the merge base, we can always have Git find it for us:

```
git merge-base --all <hash-of-J> <hash-of-L>
```

will spit out the hash ID of commit `H`.  Since no commit can ever be changed once it's made, the backwards connections from `J` and `L` will always lead backwards to `H`.  (Commit `M` can't be changed either, now that it exists.  It will always have this snapshot and will always point back to both `J`, as its first parent, and `L`, as its second.)

This is a true merge, and the process that *makes* a true merge combines your work with their work.  The `build_version.txt` file in commit `M` will be the result of applying the combined changes—yours and theirs—as seen from the *merge base*.  If you changed the file and they didn't, the file will match your file, because they made no changes.  Just because their file is different from yours doesn't mean you'll get *their file*.  You get the *merge base* file, plus *your changes*, plus *their changes*.  That's what merge does, by design.  There are a whole bunch of special cases you can add on here, but this is the basic form.

Comment: "Just because their file is different from yours doesn't mean you'll get their file."  
`
 "develop" branch is _newer_, my "branch1" is  month older.  
As  branch1 is behind, I want to get all NEWER files from "develop" - files that other people updated in "develop" during that month:  
 build_version.txt is one of such NEWER files (BTW, side question: git shows no conflict - why? content is   different - I did NOT change that file - it came a month ago with  
 git checkout -b branch1 on a base branch)  
So how can I get branch1 with new stuff from "develop"?

Comment: *Time* is irrelevant: only *commits* are relevant. Find the merge base. Diff the merge base against each branch tip. That shows you what changed. If you want some file contents changed further after the merge, make a new commit that changes those file contents. Seriously, run those two literal `git diff --find-rename` commands; it's very helpful to see what Git sees. Run the `git merge-base` command first, to find the hash ID of the merge base commit.

Comment: Thanks, will do as you suggested.
Appreciate so useful information about commits and merge!

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you get in your file is the merge (combination) of *your version* of the file (branch *My*) and the version in branch *M*.

When you say it is *your version* do you mean it is exactly the same? When merging, the changes of both branches should be there.

You can check if your file has actually changed after the merge with the following command:

```sh
git diff M <my file>
```

And you can check if the merge has produced any change with one the following commands:

```sh
git diff HEAD^1 <my file>
git diff HEAD^2 <my file> # depends which one is the ancestor from branch 'My'
```

Comment: "You can check if your file has actually changed after the merge with the following command:"
    
I see that it's still my old file via a Windows editor or in IntelliJ. I did not change that file, it was not part of my set of changes

Comment: I see. If the file was not changed, then it is ok that it did not change with the merge. In order to avoid misunderstandings, I'd suggest that you publish the repo (the one with the M and My branches) in github so that we can try, see, and comment.